# SIM card transferrable between iPhone models?

Tags: iphone, sim

My iPhone SE is not working anymore and someone has offered me an older (2015 - she doesn't know the model) iPhone that her husband bought shortly before his death.

Can I transfer my SIM card (Deutsche Telecom)from my iPhone SE into any other model of iPhone?  I'm assuming it's unlocked as he used it before his death.

Comment: Is this about physical SIM card fit or more about carrier locking or something else?

Comment: I'm just trying to find out if it's feasible to use this free phone with my existing SIM card and I didn't know what parameters I should consider.  I investigated a bit and some said that the carrier also makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you are not using a carrier locked iPhone and using a standard SIM card, it can be easily transferred from one iPhone to another.

However, newer iPhones support cellular and connectivity technologies which may not be available on older models. For e.g. iPhone 5s and earlier lack support for 4G networking. You may wish to keep this in mind.